# What happened during the adult scene in "300: Rise of an Empire"?

Tags: plot-explanation, 300-rise-of-an-empire

I've seen this movie [300: Rise of an Empire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1253863/) last night in theatres in our country and few scenes were removed as it has explicit content. I'm eager to know what happened during the scene.

In the middle of the movie, Artemisia asks Themistokles for a secret meet and tries to seduce him and asks him to join her side and Themistokles kisses her as if he fell for her charm and the next scene we were shown was, Artemisia yelling at Themistokles and saying something like

> Artemisia : Get this filth out of my sight.

My guess is, Themistokles pretended that he was seduced and after doing what he wanted he might have said to her that he didn't wanna join her, so she yelled at him.

Can anyone post the entire conversation happened during that scene as an answer? I'd like to know what exactly happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To more directly sum up what you're looking for:

> Artemisia invites Themistocles to her ship after he bests two of her
>   generals in battle. The plan is to get him to join her so she can
>   destroy Greece.
>
> Themistocles agrees to board her ship. He boards her ship.
>
> Artemisia tells Themistocles she knows he has no reinforcements coming in time
>   for the next battle, and that she can keep throwing ships and
>   resources at him for months on end. She offers to let Themistocles join her at her side.
>
> **They have sex. The dialog you're missing here is a lot of panting and
>   screaming as the two throw one another around the room.**
>
> Themistocles refuses her offer.
>
> Artemisia throws him off her ship.

There is literally no dialog you're missing that's key to the plot or character development. They have violent sex, and that's pretty much it. A copy of the script will likely not be available as the movie is less than a week old on theaters, but again, it would be pointless.

---

The key thing to remember with Artemisia is that **she absolutely despises the Greeks**. She doesn't just hate them, she wants them eradicated from the world. This is due to her people being ransacked by Greeks in her childhood, with her being taken captive and used as a child sex slave for years until her usefulness to her captors wore thin and they abandoned her, leaving her for dead in the streets.

However, she knows talent when she sees it, and always seeks an opportune moment.

She invited Themistocles to her ship in the hopes of seducing him not only with her body, but with the potential for power. Themistocles knows how strong the Persian forces are, and Artemsia attempts to bring this to light (*"I can throw forces at you for months..."*) while offering him a place by her side and all the power he could ever dream of. The two engage in sex, but when Themistocles finishes and refuses her offer, and renews her vow to eradicate the Greeks. She tells her guard to, "Get this filth out of my sight," because she views all Greeks as filth, and is attempting to insult him for having just taken advantage of her.

Whether Themistocles let down his guard in the heat of passion, or knew what he was doing in an attempt to enrage Artemisia isn't really the point of the scene. What is, is that **Artemisia is used by the Greeks yet again**. She was hopeful to lure him to her side, with all his knowledge of the Greek forces and brilliant military tactics, but instead was used for sex, rejected, and now yet another Greek gets to return to his people and brag about how they used her. Themistocles might have been trying to play mind games with her in an effort to throw off her own sense of strategy, but again, the point was to show that Artemisia gets used one final time, and believing Themistocles to be dead at the end of the next battle, returns to Xerxes believing she has won, only to be killed by Themistocles in a later battle.

Comment: @ MattD I understood the entire movie but the adult scene is removed in the theater so in turn I didn't know what Artemisia and Themistokles conversed with each other. I just want to know the conversation(or dialogues) happened between those two. May be "plot-explanation" tag that I put in my question might have confused you. I'll remove it. Could you remove the explanation part in your answer and post the dialogues between Artemisia and Themistokles in adult scene?

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is way better than required for this question. He just want's some dialogue transcription, that's all. It's the answer this question deserves, but not the one it needs right now. ;-)

Comment: Getting a transcript of a movie that's currently running in theaters will be a bit hard. The gist of the dialog is Artemisia is taunting Themistokles, bragging about the fact that she can throw ships at him for months while he can't. She then offers him a place by her side, they screw, he refuses, she gets pissed and throws him out. I still feel i cover that fairly well, but yeah, getting a transcript of a movie that hasn't been in theaters a week will be very hard.

Comment: @MattD Well, that sums it up pretty sufficiently. Saying there isn't anything he missed seems enough. I guess *"Themistocles refuses her offer."* is the part that was missing in his version. But I agree that the particular dialogue is irrelevant. +1 for addressing the actual question.

Comment: @chaitanya89 Is there something more I can add/research to try and answer your question?

Comment: @MattD No Matt, Your answer is fine. So, I didn't miss any dialogues other than sex.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen the movie and the script hasn't been made available online yet, but quoting from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/300%3a_Rise_of_an_Empire):

> Impressed with Themistocles' skills, Artemisia has him brought onto
>   her ship, where they have sex. She offers him a place in her army, but
>   he refuses, causing her to swear revenge.

So effectively she seduced him, he allowed her, but he refused to join her army which is what led to her throwing him out.

Comment: @ Andrew Martin Thanks for answering but I'd like to know the exact conversation happened during the scene. May be the persons who saw this movie could help me.